# Multiple Queries PHP7 - find the bug

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to show the table I created and insert a new value into it. 
Separately, both works. But together something is missing.

Below the PHP Code:

```
<?php

$dbhost = "host";
$dbuser = "user";
$dbpass = "passowrd";
$dbname = "dbname";

//Connect to MySQL Server
$link = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

//Select Database
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());




// Retrieve data from Query String
$age = $_GET['age'];
$sex = $_GET['sex'];
$wpm = $_GET['wpm'];

// Escape User Input to help prevent SQL Injection
$age = mysql_real_escape_string($age);
$sex = mysql_real_escape_string($sex);
$wpm = mysql_real_escape_string($wpm);
```

//THESE TWO LINES DON'T WORK

```
$query = "INSERT INTO dbname (name, age) VALUES ('mate', 19);";
$query .= "SELECT * FROM dbname";


//Execute query
$qry_result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

//Build Result String
$display_string = "<table>";
$display_string .= "<tr>";
$display_string .= "<th>Name</th>";
$display_string .= "<th>Age</th>";
$display_string .= "<th>Sex</th>";
$display_string .= "<th>WPM</th>";
$display_string .= "</tr>";

// Insert a new row in the table for each person returned
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry_result)){
   $display_string .= "<tr>";
   $display_string .= "<td>$row[name]</td>";
   $display_string .= "<td>$row[age]</td>";
   $display_string .= "<td>$row[sex]</td>";
   $display_string .= "<td>$row[wpm]</td>";
   $display_string .= "</tr>";
}

echo "Query: " . $query . "<br />";
$display_string .= "</table>";

echo $display_string;

?>
```

The thing is if I write only one line likes here:
$query = "select * from dbname";
it works fine.

What is wrong with the two lines?

Comment: It can be achieved using `mysqli` instead of `mysql` (which is deprecated and removed in PHP7). Check http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php.

Comment: I might have done it wrong, but myupdated version is not working better really

Comment: How did you manage to run `mysql` api on PHP7?

Comment: And second - `mysql` api __does not__ support multiple queries.

Comment: *"Multiple Queries PHP7"* - `mysql_` was "deleted" from PHP 7. The question was closed with 2 relevant duplicates.

Comment: @u_mulder they *probably* could using the [shim for ext/mysql in PHP 7+](https://github.com/dshafik/php7-mysql-shim) yet I *highly* doubt they're using that.